# Audio won't play until after I let go of key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an FPS game and I got everything covered for the most part.

- Walking
- Sprinting
- Crouching
- Jumping
- Gravity

However, I'm trying to implement a system where, whenever you hold down the LeftShift button, it will also play this sprinting Audio.

The problem is, whenever I'm holding the Shift button, I'm running, but the audio won't play until AFTER I let go of the shift button.

I haven't found any other forums with a similar issue as mine. I was wondering if anyone could help me identify the issue? Thank you and apologies in advanced if the answer is obvious, I'm quite new.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour

{

```
public CharacterController controller;

public float speed = 12f;

public float jumpHeight = 3f;

//Gravity

public float gravity = -9.81f;

Vector3 velocity;

//Sprinting

public bool isSprinting;

public float sprintingMultiplier;

//Crouching

public bool isCrouching;

public float crouchingMultiplier;

public float crouchingHeight = 2f;

public float standingHeight = 4f;

//Ground check

bool isGrounded;

public Transform groundCheck;

public float groundDistance = 0.4f;

public LayerMask groundMask;

void Update()

{

    //Ground check

    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)

    {

        velocity.y = -2f;

    }

    //Walking

    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * y;

    //Jumping

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)

    {

        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);

    }

    //Sprinting

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))

    {

        isSprinting = true;

    }

    else

    {

        isSprinting = false;

    }

    if (isSprinting == true)

    {

        move *= sprintingMultiplier;

        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Run");

    }

    //Crouching

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C))

    {

        isCrouching = true;

    }

    else

    {

        isCrouching = false;

    }

    if (isCrouching == true)

    {

        controller.height = crouchingHeight;

        move *= crouchingMultiplier;

    }

    else

    {

        controller.height = standingHeight;

    }

    //Gravity

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the type `AudioManager` and what exactly `Play` does there I can only guess it is somewhere using an [`AudioSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html).

And note that [`AudioSource.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) will always (**re**)start the audio clip.

> If `AudioSource.clip` is set to the same clip that is playing then the clip will sound like it is re-started. AudioSource will assume any Play call will have a new audio clip to play.

Therefore, since you call that line **every frame** you are constantly restarting that clip -> it can only finally play to end after you let go of the key and don't restart it anymore.

---

So you either want to make sure you play the sound only via `GetButtonDown` and e.g. rather use [`PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html), this way the sound is fully played once even though another sound is started meanwhile.

Or you would have to make sure to check which clip is currently playing and if the same clip is already playing then skip the `Play` call.

Both would kinda have to happen within your `AudioManager` implementation you don't show us ...